# external jars on hadoop 0.20.203

Tags: hadoop

I have to work with hadoop 0.20.203.I try to run a job that needs some external jars but I can't find out how to include them.
I have tried
1) -libjars
2) putting the jars $HADOOP_HOME/lib
but none of them seems to work.
Is there any way?

Comment: Could you share: 1. the actual errors you are seeing, 2. the setup of your cluster (pseudo or full cluster)

Comment: I get classnotfoundexception for a class that's in a jar that I include in -libjars.I have tried this in both single and multi cluster nodes

Comment: Again, can you share the actual stack trace - i'd like to know if this error occurs in job submission, or actual task execution

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right but you also need to include the .jar file in the HADOOP_CLASSPATH which you can modify in the file $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site file.  restart your cluster for it to take effect.

Comment: I've managed to do it in my single node cluster.But I cannot do it in a multi node cluster with cdh4 installed.Anyway,I 'm trying another cluster with hadoop 1.0.3 now.Thank you for the answer.